# Why am I getting this [Broken pipe] error?

Tags: pipe, c

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to do a buffer overflow attack.

Here's the C program I wrote and am trying to attack:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

void f();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("argc : %d\n", argc);
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d] : %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    printf("End of program\n");
    return 0;
}

void f()
{
    printf("You got to the hidden function!\n");
}
```

... compiled with:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Here's my Python3 injection script:

```
# inject.py
push = "A" * 1000
print(push)
```

I tried 3 methods to pipe the output of `inject.py` to `test`:

```
# attempt 1
$ ./test <(python3 inject.py)
argc : 2
argv[0] : ./test
argv[1] : /dev/fd/63
End of program
$ Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
^C
```

^ Here it actually made the 2nd `$` without my input and I had to `ctrl+C` out after it froze

```
# attempt 2
$ python3 inject.py | ./test
argc : 1
argv[0] : ./test
End of program
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

```
# attempt 3
$ ./test <(python3 -c "print(\"A\"*1000)")
argc : 2
argv[0] : ./test
argv[1] : /dev/fd/63
End of program
$ Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
^C
```

^ This one is similar to attempt 1

I believe what I'm doing is similar to the many buffer overflows I've seen on YouTube. I'd expected a `SegFault` but instead got `Broken pipe` errors.

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting `Broken pipe` instead of `SegFault`s?

Clarification: What I'm asking for is not "How to do a buffer overflow attack?", but rather "Why am I getting the `Broken pipe` error and how can I fix it?". Since this is a problem with the *nix command line, I believe this is within this community's scope.

Comment: Why do you expect a segfault? What buffer do you think you are overflowing? Hint: normally there is a char array on the stack which provides the fixed size memory area that you overfill. The `SIGPIPE` is because the python is writing data to a pipe that has become closed.

Comment: I think I did something wrongly with the piping since the same error happens with ```push = "A"*10``` instead of ```push = "A"*1000```

Comment: Your program doesn't read anything, so to a large extent it doesn't matter if you attempt to write 1 byte or a million.

Comment: Why doesn't it read? I included ```(int argc, char *argv[])``` to make it read command line inputs.

Comment: @JohnZhau and did you use the command line inputs to read anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this group is about Unix questions, not how to use exploits.

Comment: I'm not asking how to use the exploit. I'm asking why I'm getting the ```Broken pipe``` error which is a *nix problem with the command line. I can't start my exploitation with the ```Broken pipe```.

Answer (score 3):

You get a "broken pipe" error in the Python program since you are not reading the data outputted by it.  Your C program totally ignores its standard input stream, and the stream is closed when `test` terminates, leaving the Python program trying to write to a pipe that nobody is listening to.

A pipe is also used when you employ a process substitution in `bash` (`<(...)`), which is why you get the same issue there.  In these examples, the data is not arriving over standard input, but from a file indicated by the command's first command line argument.  You never open this file.

To fix this, make sure that the C program consumes all input from standard input, or from the pathname indicated by the command's first argument.

Your current code would not cause a buffer overrun, segmentation fault, or any other error, in your C code.

I'm assuming that you'd like to cause a buffer overrun in the C code somehow.  You would do that by reading the data from the Python code into a too small buffer, for example.

By the way, the Python code does not need to be Python, it could be a simple shell command that produces a lot of data, such as the `yes` utility (possibly piped through `head -n 1000` or similar, as in `yes A | head -n 1000`).

Comment: Can you provide an example fix? I've tried what I know but that was the result

Comment: @JohnZhau As I said, you have to read the data coming from the Python program. If the data is received via a pipe or redirection on standard input, just read from there, otherwise open the file in `argv[1]` and read from that instead.

Comment: I thought ```python3 inject.py | ./test``` does just that. From what I know, python3's ```print``` outputs to ```stdout``` and ```int main(int argc, char *argv[])``` takes its command line inputs from ```stdin```. If that's true, the python3's ```stdout``` should be piped as ```stdin``` for ```./test```, but it seems that's not correct. I'm still unsure as to where my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @JohnZhau Well, that pipeline sends data into your C program's standard input stream. The command line arguments of the C program have nothing to do with the data sent by the Python program in this case. You are not reading the data sent by the Python code, so it blocks. When the C code terminates, the Python program fails with "broken pipe" (because the data was never read).

Comment: In that case, how should I change my C code to take in the piped ```stdin```?

Comment: @JohnZhau Reading data is done with, for example `scanf()`, `fgets()` or any of a number of other functions.